# How are "types" defined in this module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum, p-groups, quotient-set

Note: This might end up being a question about a simple concept that I forgot about (I am very tired at the time of writing this, after all), so maybe try skipping to the bottom.

I'm learning about modules over a PID in abstract algebra (Nicholson) and there's this theorem (7.2.5, if for whatever reason you want to know):

> Let $R$ be a PID, let $p \in R$ be a prime, and let $M$ be a finitely generated, nonzero, $p$-module over $R$. Then there is a decomposition
> $$
> M = Rx_1 \oplus \dots \oplus Rx_t
> $$
> where $o(x_i) = p^{m_i}$, with $m_1 \geq m_2 \geq \cdots \geq m_t \geq 1$. Furthermore, the integers $t, m_1, m_2, \dots, m_t$ are uniquely determined by $M$.
> More generally, if $K \subseteq M$ is any submodule and $K = Ry_1 \oplus \dots \oplus R y_u$ where $o(y_i) = p^{k_i}$ with $k_1 \geq \cdots \geq k_u \geq 1$, then $u \leq t$ and $k_i \leq m_i$ for each $i=1,\dots,u$.

I'm not confused about the theorem, although it is relevant. It basically says that given such a direct sum, the exponent of the orders of the $x_i$ uniquely determine $M$ given the ring $R$. Hence, we have the following definitions:

1. The $t$-tuple $(m_1, \dots, m_t)$ is called the *type* of the module $M$
2. The elements $p^{m_1}, \dots, p^{m_t}$ are called the *elementary divisors* of $M$.

But then the author says that given a sequence of integers $m_1 \geq m_2 \geq \cdots \geq m_t$ the module
$$
R/Rp^{m_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus R/Rp^{m_t}
$$
is of type $(m_1, \dots, m_t)$. Why? In the definition, $M$ is the sum of principal ideals, but not here - it's just quotient rings. I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, can someone help me out?

Comment: The $Rx_i$ are cyclic submodules of $M$, not principal ideals. (They would only be principal ideals if $M$ were $R$ itself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient module $R/Ra$ is generated by the coset of $1\in R$, which has order $a$.  So it can also be written in the form $Rx$ where $x$ is an element of order $a$.